# Fullcalendar using 'allDay: false' is not working resize event

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I searched for answers to many questions in StackOverflow but could not come to a conclusion for solving this problem.

1. When I put "allDay: false" in the events code, I can't resize the event. but the date in the calendar will be complete and correct.

ts code:

```
this.calendarOptions = {
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next',
          right: 'title',
        },
        dayMaxEventRows: 1,
        height: '520px',
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        displayEventTime: false,
        events: [
          {title: 'test1', start: new Date('2022-01-05'), end: new Date('2022-01-06'), allDay: false},
          {title: 'test2', start: new Date('2022-01-09'), end: new Date('2022-01-11'), allDay: false},
          {title: 'test3', start: new Date('2022-01-15'), end: new Date('2022-01-17'), allDay: false},
          {title: 'test4', start: new Date('2022-01-25'), end: new Date('2022-01-27'), allDay: false}
        ],
        selectable: true,
        select: this.selectDate.bind(this),
        dayMaxEvents: 3,
        droppable: true,
        editable:true,
        eventDrop: function (info) {
          
          
        },
        eventChange: (info) => {
      
        },
      };
```

display:
[image]

2. When I put "allDay: true" in the events code, I can resize the event. But the date on the calendar is the end date wrong by one day.

ts code:

```
this.calendarOptions = {
            headerToolbar: {
              left: 'prev,next',
              right: 'title',
            },
            dayMaxEventRows: 1,
            height: '520px',
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            displayEventTime: false,
            events: [
              {title: 'test1', start: new Date('2022-01-05'), end: new Date('2022-01-06'), allDay: true},
              {title: 'test2', start: new Date('2022-01-09'), end: new Date('2022-01-11'), allDay: true},
              {title: 'test3', start: new Date('2022-01-15'), end: new Date('2022-01-17'), allDay: true},
              {title: 'test4', start: new Date('2022-01-25'), end: new Date('2022-01-27'), allDay: true}
            ],
            selectable: true,
            select: this.selectDate.bind(this),
            dayMaxEvents: 3,
            droppable: true,
            editable:true,
            eventDrop: function (info) {
              
              
            },
            eventChange: (info) => {
          
            },
          };
```

display:
[image]

3. When I did not put "allDay: false" in the events code, I can resize the event. But the date on the calendar is the end date wrong by one day.

ts code:

```
this.calendarOptions = {
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next',
          right: 'title',
        },
        dayMaxEventRows: 1,
        height: '520px',
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        displayEventTime: false,
        events: [
          {title: 'test1', start: ('2022-01-05'), end: ('2022-01-06')},
          {title: 'test2', start: ('2022-01-09'), end: ('2022-01-11')},
          {title: 'test3', start: ('2022-01-15'), end: ('2022-01-17')},
          {title: 'test4', start: ('2022-01-25'), end: ('2022-01-27')}
        ],
        selectable: true,
        select: this.selectDate.bind(this),
        dayMaxEvents: 3,
        droppable: true,
        editable:true,
        eventDrop: function (info) {
          
          
        },
        eventChange: (info) => {
      
        },
      };
```

display:
[image]
what should I do for the date of the event is displayed correctly and can adjust the event size.

Comment: Why do you assume, that end date `2022-01-27` is supposed to overflow in calendar UI to date cell 27? End date does not mean end of the day, rather ending period on day 27. Other calendar UI's I've seen are using same principle. Having not worked with this specific calendar, but I assume what is happening, is that when you select `allDay: false` it also adds time to your date e.g `2022-01-27T04:57:33.530Z` but with `allDay:true` time is set to 00:00:00 or removed. Please inspect and let use know what kind of date obj's is calendar consuming when allDay is true/false.

Comment: Making an event allDay does not prevent it from being resized. I think maybe you are misattributing whatever problem you're experiencing to this fact. And Joosep.P is correct - as per the fullCalendar documentation, the end dates of events are **exclusive**.